# Resetting a react-select field to the first value of array with button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I want to create a select input where the value is always reset to the first value of the options array

```
import Select from 'react-select';
import {useState} from 'react';
function Component(){

  const options = [{value: "something", label: "Something"}, ...]
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [inputValue2, setInputValue2] = useState("");
  

  return (
    <div>
      <Select 
        options={options}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.value)}
        value={inputValue}
      />
      <Select 
        options={options}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue2(e.value)}
        value={inputValue2}
      />
      <button onClick={handleReset}>Clear all Values</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When the button is clicked, all values of the select fields should be reset to the first value of the options array, how can I achieve this?

This is really important to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it that if nothing it selected then the first value of the array will be selected.

```
value={inputValue || options[0]}
```

The handleReset function essentially resets the values to the empty string in which case the select field will fall back onto the first value of the array.

**Note: this will also set the select field to the first value when the page loads before a selection has been made.**

*Remember that when using the react-select package, when setting the value, the component expects both the value and the label (i.e. {value: "1", label: "one"})*

```js
import Select from 'react-select';
import {useState} from 'react';
function Component(){

    const options = [{value: "1", label: "one"}, {value: "2", label: "two"}]
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    const [inputValue2, setInputValue2] = useState("");
    
    const handleReset = () => {
       setInputValue(options[0]);
       setInputValue2(options[0]);
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <Select 
        options={options}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e)}
        value={inputValue || options[0]}
        />
        <Select 
        options={options}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue2(e)}
        value={inputValue2 || options[0]}
        />
        <button onClick={handleReset}>Clear all Values</button>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work, the value is reset but the select field still has the same value from before

Comment: not sure I understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: If I implement it like this, the function works. The value is reset, but pictorially it is not shown that the value was reset.

For example "Select something" is the first value in the array. I want that when I select something, that value is shown that I have selected that. But the value is not shown, even after I selected something, the select field says "Select something".

Comment: edited the answer. lmk if this works (and if it does feel free to pick this as the accepted answer :)

Comment: I love you! I am trying to solve that shit since days!